# Nearby jail's signal jammer affecting cellphone and devices using 2.4GHz band

Tags: wireless, interference, cellphone, telecommunications

I just rented an apartment that seemed perfect at the first sight.

However, once I moved in, I noticed a lot of instability on my cellphone signal. I found that odd, so I did some research and discovered that there's a jail in the neighborhood using a cellphone signal jammer system.

I didn't care too much at first, because I don't make or receive phone calls frequently. Actually, I could live a happy life using telegram/whatsapp calls over the 5GHz band from my internet router, since this frequency range doesn't seem to be affected.

The problem is that the jammer is affecting older devices that need to connect to the router over 2.4GHz, as well as bluetooth devices.

As a layman on the subject, is there something I can do to at least weaken the jammer's effect on my devices? Maybe doing something to the windows/balcony door, so they work similar to a faraday cage, I really don't know.

Comment: you should call your spectrum regulatory institution (FCC if you're in the US, for example). A) it's not a given that the prison operates legally even on-premises, some have simply "done before asking" in the past, and B) it's most definitely not OK that they jam the surroundings. FCC (or their international equivalents) should be *really* quick sorting that out.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that you are in fact not a prisoner and that you are not seeking to find a way to illegally call/harass witnesses or victims?

Comment: @Andyaka while I share your sentiment, I don't think it's realistic that a prisoner decorates their windows with copper mesh :)

Comment: Prisoners will go to great lengths to be able to use mobile phones while locked up. I have close family members who are "screws" and I've seen what precautions they need to take to stop this happening. I've also heard of the unhygienic methods that a lot of prisoners will undertake to get phones inside jails.

Comment: @Andyaka If I'm in prison and make my cell a faraday cage, wouldn't it prevent my signal from reaching outside? :D

Comment: Why ask me. I never mentioned faraday cage until this comment.

Comment: Actually, I mentioned in the question, as a possible way to deal with the problem ;)

Comment: @Caconde unrealistic, though. Faraday-caging is more complicated than that, and shielding an apartement is hard. RF-silent rooms are pretty expensive to build. "My PS4 doesn't work, but I have money for an RF-silent room": Well, then buy a villa somewhere else. There's common misunderstandings about faraday cages, and they can't just be build by putting some wire with a maximum distance across a few openings. Also, you only have symptoms, but you don't even know what to specifically shield against. You'll also not buy a spectrum analyzer. Again, this is your spectrum regulator's job,not yours.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying comment, Marcus. As I said, I have no knowledge on the subject, so I'm prone to dumb questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a layman on the subject, is there something I can do to at least weaken the jammer's effect on my devices?

Sure, but it's not your job, and under any legislation I can think of, it's not your financial duty to remedy the problem. (and it's going to be rather expensive, too)

You should call your spectrum regulatory institution (FCC if you're in the US, for example).

1. it's not a given that the prison operates legally even on-premises, some have simply "done before asking" in the past (we've had dozens of people asking how to build/deploy/fix their jammers, without even as much as considering the legality of what they're doing), and
2. it's most definitely not OK that they jam the surroundings in the general case. FCC (or their international equivalents) should be *really* quick sorting that out, in my experience. "Hey, I've got someone seemingly intentionally jamming in our neighborhood", without even specifying who that might be, would usually make Bundesnetzagentur send a radio surveillance car and then rather quickly issue a desist directive against the causer and quite likely also a fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I live in Brazil and our authorities   are recognized worldwide for not giving a s#!t about the people. A complaint to the regulatory agency here would take years to reach an outcome.  In september our supreme court judged a lawsuit filled in 1895. It took 125 years to finish!! I'm just looking for a palliative solution, so I can plug older devices to the router, as well as use my PS4  without reseting the controllers each 10 minutes :)

Comment: What you say is completely irrelevant to the problem at hand. ANACOM is your agency. And your only chance; if spectrum regulation doesn't regulate the spectrum, well, you're basically out of possible options there.

Comment: That's sad. I'll have to live with that if the regulatory agency is the only option. There are even other government buildings in the area suffering with the same problems - not the pS4 problem :) - and nothing has been done. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: you know how government institution stop working and how corruption thrives: by people stopping to even try asking for them to do their job. Who says anyone has asked? You're also clearly in no position of equipment nor experience to really diagnose what's going on. What you have is called a *hunch*, not even a strong clue. You need someone with the right measurement equipment no matter what. And guess who has that? Your regulatory body. So for feck's sake, stop complaining they won't do their job before **you personally** know they don't.